# CSS Centering - What's The Best Approach To Replacing The Align Attribute?

Tags: html, css

Sorry to beat a dead horse, but I need some advice on centering the contexts inside a div tag. I have a div tag with a table inside it (the div with the context class). I have an align attribute on it and it produces the results I want, but I would like to do this properly with css. If I set the div's 'text-align' to 'center', that propagates down into the table cells, which is not what I want. So... how do I center the div's contents without affecting the table cells? [Here is a fiddle for this code.](http://jsfiddle.net/Halcyon/V9JRP/)

```
<style type="text/css">
    * { font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; }
    .container { padding-bottom: 10px; }
    .content { background-color: #EEEEEE; }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div>Demo</div>
    <div class="content" align="center">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item 1</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">remove</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item 2</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">remove</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item 3</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">remove</a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Item 4</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">remove</a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Item 5</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the `align` attribute, do this:

```
table { margin: 0 auto; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/V9JRP/1/

Of course, you may want to use an ID or class selector to select the table...

The rule is this: If the element is a block-level element, and you want to center it, set `margin:0 auto;` on it. This may require the width of that element to be set explicitly.

Comment: I didn't try the margin approach because I've only used it on div elements with a fixed width. Let's say the table was replaced with a div of an unknown width. What would you use in that case to center the contents?

Comment: @Halcyon Would the `width` of that DIV be explicitly set via CSS? If no, then that DIV would be 100% wide, which means that centering wouldn't apply... How to center the contents of the DIV depends on what the contents are. If it's text (or other inline content), then set `text-align: center` on the DIV. If it's block-level content, then set `margin: 0 auto` on that content...

Comment: You [don't need](http://jsfiddle.net/HDYb4/) a fixed width to center with `margin`.

Comment: @bookcasey you are correct. You don't need a fixed width to center with margin. I just tried centering a div with an unknown width and found that setting it's display to table will allow the div to center.

Answer (score 2):

```
div.content table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table {width:100px;margin:0 auto;}
```

That should set you right, just specify the width you are after.